# Как заменить это на конструкцию if-else

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, бот

Во многих гайдах по созданию telegram-ботов на python есть такая конструкция:
`@bot.message_handler(content_types = ["text"]) def...`
Я бы хотел сделать это через if-else, но в документации по pyTelegramBotApi никакого message_handler не нашёл, и других альтернатив определения типа содержимого сообщения тоже не нашёл, да и, вообще, методы в документации какие-то странные: не совпадают с тем, что приходится использовать. Например, в документации sendMessage, но компилятор говорит, что его не существует, работает только send_message, который в документации не присутствует. У меня, конечно, есть свои догадки по этому поводу, но хотелось бы знать точно). Пожалуйста, объясните мне момент с if-else и расскажите, что не так я понимаю в документации.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот способ обработки сообщений без использования декораторов:

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)

upd = bot.get_updates()
last_upd = upd[-1]
print(last_upd)
last_msg = last_upd.message
print(last_msg)

if last_msg.text == "Hi":
    bot.send_message(last_msg.chat.id, "Hello, how are you?")

bot.polling()
```

Здесь используется метод .get_updates(), с помощью него можно узнать последние обновления (last_upd). Из последнего обновления получаем сообщение от пользователя last_upd.message (там содержится информация о пользователе, дата отправки, сам текст сообщения и тд.) Далее информацию из объекта last_msg (last_upd.message) можно использовать, как в примере выше. (единственная проблема, ответ на сообщение отправляется один раз, видимо, бот отключается и его надо каждый раз обновлять)

Comment: Спасибо большое! Позвлишь ли ты узнать мне твой контакт, чтобы я смог когда-нибудь спросить у тебя что-нибудь по этой тематике? Обещаю, что не буду занимать много твоего времени!)

Comment: На самом деле я не так уж и хорошо в этом разбираюсь, но если нужно то можно писать в тг: @Vasily_Esipenko. А так лучше всего посмотреть документацию по pyTelegramBotAPI (https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI). Также есть и другие библиотеки для работы с api телеграма: aiogram (https://aiogram.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)  и python-telegram-bot (https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot)

Comment: Благодарю)   ыафываыфваываыфваыфва

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.message_handler - это декоратор (функция, которая обертывает другую функцию)
```

Ниже после этого декоратора можно добавить функцию, которая будет содержать дополнительные условия. Например:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def text_handler(message):
    if message.text == "Привет!":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Добрый день!")
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Я вас не понимаю...")
```

Comment: Ясно, но я хотел узнать немного другое. Как мне без использования декоратора иметь доступ к message? В различных гайдах пишут, что этот декоратор упрощает код, т.к. используется вместо if'а, а я хочу сделать с if)